# How to add new notification channels automatically on Android, when a notification is received?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, notifications

i can do it if the user clicks on the notification and opens the app.
i'm sending a channel name and id with my notifications then using this in my onCreate

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("channelId");
            String channelName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("channelName");
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

or if the app is foreground, onMessageReceived is called so i can just do:

```
        String channelName = remoteMessage.getData().get("channelName");
        String channelId = remoteMessage.getData().get("channelId");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId , channelName ,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

but if the app is closed or in the background and user doesn't click on the notification, i can't create the new channel

here's the python side:

```
def sendMulticast(notificationTitle, notificationMessage, notificationLink, notificationTokens, imageLink, channelName, channelId):
   if len(notificationTokens)>0:
        try :
            message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
        tokens = list(dict.fromkeys(notificationTokens)),
        data={"link":notificationLink, "channelName":channelName, "channelId":channelId},
        android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
        priority='high',
        
        notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(title=notificationTitle,
            body=notificationMessage,
            image=imageLink,
            color='#ff0000', default_light_settings="true", priority="max", default_vibrate_timings="true", default_sound ="true", channel_id=channelId
        ),
    ),
        )

            response = messaging.send_multicast(message)
            print('Successfully sent message:', response)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

Comment: as far as I know, if you send the notification only with data, it fires the onMesaageReceived even in background, so anyway I'd create the channel inside onMessageeceived for both scenarios (foreground and background)

Comment: @Avital  thanks this code worked 
    `message = messaging.MulticastMessage(tokens = list(dict.fromkeys(tokensToSend)),         data={"link":notificationLink, "channelName":channelName, "image":imageLink, "channelId":channelId, "title":notificationTitle, "channelId":notificationTitle, "body":notificationMessage},)`